# Remove all punctuation from string, except if it's between digits

Tags: python, regex, string, text, mining

I have a text that contains words and numbers. I'll give a representative example of the text:

```
string = "This is a 1example of the text. But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data"
```

I'd like to convert it to something like:

```
"This is a  1 example of the text But it only is  2.5  percent of all data"
```

So removing **punctuation** (can be `.` `,` or any other in `string.punctuation`) and also put a space between digits and words when it is concatenated. But keep the floats like 2.5 in my example.

I used the following code:

```
item = "This is a 1example of the text. But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data"
item = ' '.join(re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", item).split())
# This a start but not there yet !
#item = ' '.join([x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in item.split() if x not in string.digits])
item = ' '.join(re.split(r'(\d+)', item) )
print item
```

The result is :

```
 >> "This is a  1 example of the text. But, it only is  2 . 5  percent of all data"
```

I'm almost there but can't figure out that last peace.

Comment: In your example output you still have punctuation? do you want to remove that or not?

Comment: @Roelant I think that's the last peace.

Comment: @Roelant I just updated the post I made a mistake. Please take a look at it. I want to remove punctuation but not from `2.5` and likewise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex lookarounds like this:

```
(?<!\d)[.,;:](?!\d)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAeuqB/1)**

The idea is to have a character class gathering the punctuation you want to replace and use lookarounds to match punctuation that does not have digits around

```
regex = r"(?<!\d)[.,;:](?!\d)"

test_str = "This is a 1example of the text. But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data"

result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str, 0)
```

Result is:

```
This is a 1example of the text But it only is 2.5 percent of all data
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico looks like it's the best answer so far !

Answer (score 1):

Okay folks, here is an answer (the best ? I don't know but it seems to work) :

```
item = "This is a 1example 2Ex of the text.But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data?"
#if there is two strings contatenated with the second starting with capital letter
item = ' '.join(re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", item).split())
#if a word starts with a digit like "1example"
item = ' '.join(re.split(r'(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)', item) )
#Magical line that removes punctuation apart from floats
item = re.sub('\S+', lambda m: re.match(r'^\W*(.*\w)\W*$', m.group()).group(1), item)
item = item.replace("  "," ")
print item
```

Comment: This takes a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Federico's answer is better, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I am out of touch with Python, but have some insight into the regexps.
My I suggest the usage of or?
I would use this regexp: `"(\d+)([a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z])(\d+)"`, and then as the replacement string use:  `"\1 \2"`
If some corner cases plague you, you can pass the back-reference to a procedure, and then deal 1-by-1, probably by checking if your "\1\2" can translate to float. TCL has such built-in functionality, Python should too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked very well.

`a = "This is a 1example of the text. But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data"
 a.replace(". ", " ").replace(", "," ")`

Notice that, in replace function there is space after punctuation. I just replaced punctuation and space with only space.

Comment: This solution applies only for `.` and `,` but in `string.punctuation` there is a lot of characters. I need something that can work for all the punctuation...

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
from itertools import groupby

s1 = "This is a 1example of the text. But, it only is 2.5 percent of all data"
s2 = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s1, str.isalpha)]
s3 = ' '.join(s2).replace("   ", "  ").replace("  ", " ")

#you can keep adding a replace for each ponctuation
s4 = s3.replace(". ", " ").replace(", "," ").replace("; "," ").replace(", "," ").replace("- "," ").replace("? "," ").replace("! "," ").replace(" ("," ").replace(") "," ").replace('" '," ").replace(' "'," ").replace('... '," ").replace('/ '," ").replace(' “'," ").replace('” '," ").replace('] '," ").replace(' ['," ")

s5 = s4.replace("  ", " ")
print(s5)
```

**Output:**

```
'This is a 1 example of the text But it only is 2.5 percent of all data'
```

P.s.: You can take a look at [Punctuation Marks](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/marks.htm) and keep adding them inside the `.replace()` function.

Comment: same comment as for @Shivam 's answer... The ponctuation doesn't contain only `.` and `,`

Comment: I know it's not the best solution, but you know that you can keep adding `.replace()`, right? I've added a few more in my example to contemplate more punctuation marks.. But I think the best approach would be using a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex approach

`([^ ]?)(?:[^\P{punct}.]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d))([^ ]?)`

Replace in a callback:

if $1 length > 0 and $2 length > 0
replace with  $1 + space + $2
else
replace with  $1$2

Expanded

```
 ( [^ ]? )                     # (1)
 (?:
      [^\P{punct}.] 
   |  
      (?<! \d )
      \.
      (?! \d )
 )
 ( [^ ]? )                     # (2)
```

If you don't want to use  logic for chars adjacent to punct
Use `(?:[^\P{punct}.]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d))` and replace with nothing.